# Matplotlib: categorical plot without strings and inversion of axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, type-conversion, categorical-data

Let's take this snippet of Python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [5,4,3,2,1,0]
x_strings = ['5','4','3','2','1','0']
y = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

plt.figure()

plt.subplot(311)
plt.plot(x, y, marker='o')

plt.subplot(312)
plt.plot(x_strings, y, marker='^', color='red')

plt.subplot(313)
plt.plot(x, y, marker='^', color='red')
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()

plt.show()
```

Which produces these three subplots:

[image]

In the top subplot the `x` values are automatically sorted increasingly despite their order in the given list. If I want to plot `x` vs. `y` exactly in the given order of `x`, then I have two possibilities:

1) Convert x values to strings and have a categorical plot -- that's the middle subplot.

2) Invert the x-axis -- that's the bottom subplot.

Question: is there any other way to do a sort of categorical plot, but without conversion of numbers into strings and without the inversion of the x-axis?

**ADD-ON:**

If I use `set_xticklabels(list)`, then for some unclear reason the first element in the list is skipped (no matter if I refer to the `x` or to the `x_strings` list), and the resulting plot is also totally strange:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [5,4,3,2,1,0]
x_strings = ['5','4','3','2','1','0']
y = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xticklabels(x)
ax.plot(x, y, marker='^', color='red')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both attempted solutions seem possible. Alternatively, you can always mimic categorical plots by plotting integer numbers and setting the ticklabels to your liking.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [5,4,3,2,1,0]
y = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(range(len(y)), y, marker='^', color='red')

ax.set_xticks(range(len(y)))
ax.set_xticklabels(x)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! My implementation of set_xticklabels() was not fully correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way to do it, without being anyhow categorical and without x-axis inversion!

```
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.set_xlim(x[0],x[-1], auto=True) # this line plays the trick
plt.plot(x, y, marker='^', color='red')
```

[image]